# SqlAlchemy - make a query where Relationship Attribute is a list

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two models:

```
class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

    stagesP_list = relationship(
        'StageP', 
        back_populates='profiles_list',
        secondary=stageP_profile
        )


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

    stagesP_list = relationship(
        'StageP', 
        back_populates='projects_list',
        secondary=stageP_project
        )
```

I need to select Profiles for which at least one value of the `Profile.stagesP_list` is contained in the `project.stagesP_list`.

Please help to compose the query or indicate the direction in which to search.

Comment: In the specific `Project`'s `stagesP_list`? Or any in the database?

Comment: in the specific project.stagesP_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `project` instance loaded, you can compose the following query:

```
project = ...
stageP_ids = [obj.id for obj in project.stagesP_list]

query = session.query(Profile).filter(
    Profile.stagesP_list.any(StageP.id.in_(stageP_ids))
)
```

You can also perform joins on the database directly from having only `project_id`:

```
query = (
    session.query(Profile)
    .join(StageP, Profile.stagesP_list)
    .join(Project, StageP.projects_list)
    .where(Project.id == project_id)
    .distinct()
)
```

Comment: Many thanks! The first solution meets my needs